# How to identify missing typename in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there anyway to identify missing typename in VS ? Does VS at least produce some kind of warning ?

```
template<class T> 
void dum() {
  std::vector<T> dum_vector;
  typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = dum_vector.begin(); 
  // VS compiles it with or without typename, but I would like to know whether 
  // I forgot to put a typename, since without typename the code may not compile 
  // with another compiler (e.g. GCC)
}
```

Comment: "since without typename the code may not compile with another compiler" => "since without the typename the code is not well formed C++".

Comment: What version of VS are we talking about?

Comment: @FredOverflow How is this a duplicate? This question is not asking what the keywords are for or where they apply, but how to get MSVC to step down from its throne-of-uniqueness and at least *mention* when it's accepting nonstandard syntax.

Comment: @FredOverflow it is not a duplicate IMO, since I would like to know whether I forgot typename (and template) somewhere in the code. (I mean does VS somehow can be configured to provide a warning etc.)

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree with you, but pragmatic result of not well formed C++ (not obeying standards) = not compiling on another platform.

Comment: @Angew Identifying missing `typename`s by hand is possible if you know the rules ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow: What if you forget, and the compiler accepts the code?

Comment: The exact version of visual studio you want to coerce into telling you about the error might be helpful.

Comment: @FredOverflow It is also possible to write bug-free code, yet few people manage ;-) That's why we have compilers give us warnings as well as errors.

Comment: I guess if you compiled your code with GCC, then you will get compile-time error, and it will specify the lines where you must use `typename`, since GCC support the two step compilation process on template, whereas MSVC doesn't.

Comment: @AlexDan you are right, I can use GCC for that purpose, but what I am asking can I achieve same thing without using another compiler by only relying on VS.

Comment: @Angew Also, closing as "duplicate" is just so much easier than providing a related link by hand, and sometimes laziness wins... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it has 100% standard conformance, but MSVC produces [Compiler Warning (level 1) C4346](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsx7wabs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for all or most cases in which `typename` was explicitly needed. So as long as you are compiling with compiler flag `/W1` or greater you should be okay.

Comment: It is strange. I am using \W3, however not getting any warning with VS10.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in the current version of C++ (which is C++11), you don't need to write that much. You just could write this:

```
auto it = dum_vector.begin();
```

and you're done.

Note that `auto` is supported since MSVC10, so if you're using it, I would recommend you to use `auto` in place of `blah::blah::iterator`. If you're using older version, it is better to upgrade and avail benefits of C++11 features as much as possible. If you cannot do that, then it is **very unlikely** that MSVS can tell you the missing typename, given that the compiler compiles the non-Standard code in the first place!

Comment: Thanks, although I am very grateful about auto in C++11, current project that I work on haven't switched to C++11 compatible compiler yet.

Comment: Also thanks for additional note, and I also agree with that. If there is no other answers to my question I am going to accept your answer (since you try to explain why such support might not be provided).